# Copying SDL_Surface pixels into an STL container

Tags: c++, sdl, pixel-manipulation

I wrote this function that I want to use in a program, but for some reason, it fails despite nothing going wrong:

```
std::deque <std::deque <bool> > load_image(std::string & image_name){
    SDL_Surface * image = open_image(image_name);
    if (!image)
        exit(3);
    Uint32 * pixels = (Uint32 *) image -> pixels;
    std::deque <std::deque <bool> > grid(HEIGHT, std::deque <bool>(WIDTH, false));
    for(int y = 0; y < std::min(image -> h, HEIGHT); y++)
        for(int x = 0; x < std::min(image -> w, WIDTH); x++)
            grid[y][x] = (pixels[(image -> w * y) + x] == 0);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    return grid;
}
```

I'm simply trying to copy whether or not the pixel is black into the `grid`. When I run `grid[y][x]` and `(pixels[(image -> w * y) + x] == 0)` separately, the program runs fine. When I do `grid[y][x] = (pixels[(image -> w * y) + x] == 0);`, the program crashes somewhere in the middle of the image.

I'm pretty sure `(image -> w * y) + x` gets the correct pixel, no matter what `x` and `y` are limited to, so what am I not seeing??

Comment: Sounds like you're going out ot bounds on `grid` to me. Try using `at()` instead of `operator[]` and see if you get an "std::out_of_range" exception.

Comment: yep. still out of range, even though grid.at(y).at(x) works just fine

Comment: One other thing: are you sure your SDL_Surface is in 32bpp format? Have you checked `image->format->BitsPerPixel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the program crashes somewhere in the middle of the image.

You forgot to mention whether it crashes reading or writing memory. Also you could try debugging it - either via VisualStudio/gdb or by dumping values of `y` and `x` into `stderr`/`OutputDebugString`.

> grid[y][x] = (pixels[(image -> w * y) + x] == 0);

Nope.

To address single pixel use:

```
&((const char*)image->pixels)[y * image->pitch + x*image->format->BytesPerPixel];
```

or

```
(const Uint32*)((const char*)image->pixels + y * image->pitch + x*image->format->BytesPerPixel)
```

Pixel is not guaranteed to be 32bit. Also, if this is not a software surface, you'll need to lock it. See documentation for [SDL_Surface](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsurface.html) and [SDL_PixelFormat](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlpixelformat.html)